# How to search on the field that stores escaped strings?

Tags: plugin-development, search

I have custom tables in the database i.e. `g_projects` with loads of columns. Data is stored in the table using the Wordpress native insert query i.e. `$wpdb->insert`, hence they are escaped.

**For example**

**Input**: Application's Document

**Database**: Application\'s Document

The problem is how can I perform search on the escaped columns because they are stored as "Application\'s Document" whereas, I want to be able to search as "Application Document".

My query below returns nothing:

```
$wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM g_projects WHERE type=\"Application's Document\"");
```

**Edit #1**

I am using POSTMAN add-on to call my API which then uses `$wpdb->insert()` method to insert new records. Upon further investigation I observed that the slashes were actually added by the `POSTMAN` somehow because If I pass data to API using `POSTMAN` it stores escaped strings. Whereas, if I use the `$wpdb->insert()` directly it will store string without slashes as suggested below by @TheDeadMedic

**Edit #2**

This is the final edit for those who faced similar problems using POSTMAN. POSTMAN actually escapes string before passing to the `$wpdb->insert()` function. Therefore, use `$wpdb->unslash()` on the $data before passing to the insert function.

Comment: Why are you *storing* the data escaped? You only need to escape during insert, which `$wpdb->insert( $table, $data )` will already do for you.

Comment: I am not escaping data. Please see above my input and how it is stored in database.

Comment: What I'm saying is the value *stored* in the db should be `Application's Document`, not `Application\'s Document`.

Comment: I was using POSTMAN add-on to pass data to an API which use $wpdb->insert() to add new records. It looks like POSTMAN somehow escapes the string because it added slashes to escape single quote

Comment: @TheDeadMedic It looks like POSTMAN is escaping string that is why I have slashes in the database.

Comment: In which case call `wp_unslash( $data )` before you pass it to `$wpdb->insert()`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks mate. It works now - so sad I didn't know it was the PostMan's fault

Answer (score 0):

I think what TheDeadMedic is trying to say, is your data in SQL should not have escapes. You will want to run queries to remove the escapes, but that can be complicated. Until that is done, you will not be able to search for "Application's Document" and get back any results.

When escaping strings into the database, your best option is to use prepared statements. It is the most secure way to avoid breaking SQL statements with the ' character, and it also prevents SQL injection.

However, if you are on an older server that doesn't support it, you will have to use an escaping function. In PHP, MySQL has the method mysql_real_escape_string($value) which will do it for you. Just wrap all your varibles in that. It's better than nothing.

Comment: mysql_* is obsolete. Please don't use it

Comment: The point was to get him thinking in the right direction. As I mentioned above, prepared statements should be the route he goes which is MySQLi. the MySQL driver is for those on servers that do not have MySQLi (although I have no idea why anyone would stay on those servers). mysql_real_escape_string is better than nothing at all which is the only reason I mentioned it.